# $scope passes as value in attrs while controller as returns string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When values to directive is passed using $scope inside my link funciton I am able to access them using the variables attrs while if I pass values using controller as syntax I am able to access just the string as passed. Here is my code

directive call

```
<div linear-chart chart-data="salesData"></div></div>
<div linear-chart2 chart-data="ctrl.salesData2"></div></div>
```

code for directive

```
app.directive('linearChart', function($window){
   return{
      restrict:'EA',
      template:"some template",
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
           console.log(attrs.chartData);
      }
    }
}
```

here attrs.chartData displayes the data that was passed in root controller as $scope.salesData as json

```
app.directive('linearChart2', function($window){
   return{
      restrict:'EA',
      template:"some template",
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
           console.log(attrs.chartData);
      }
    }
}
```

here chartData displays just the string ctrl.salesData2. How do I proceed thanks in advance.

Comment: any demo code would be great !

Answer (score 1):

To get an object, attrs.chartData should evaluated (through the scope.$eval)

```
<div linear-chart chart-data="salesData"></div>  
console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.chartData))
```

or if you want to get json string, use {{ }}

```
<div linear-chart chart-data="{{ salesData }}"></div>
```

No matter what the syntax of controller.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biggieman/ds71sajp/22/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the object binding of the directive:

```
app.directive('linearChart2', function($window){
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        scope: {
            chartData: "="
        },
        template:"some template",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            console.log(scope.chartData);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just evaluate the given expression with `$scope.$eval`:

```
app.directive('linearChart2', function($window){
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        template:"some template",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var evaluatedData = scope.$eval(attrs.chartData);
            console.log(evaluatedData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use double braces `{{ }}` to display that content from the model:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.type = "Name";
    vm.type1 = "Address";
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      template: function(elem, attr) {
        return  attr.type;
      }
    };
  });
})(window.angular);

/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-directive-template-url-fn-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
  <div my-customer type="{{ctrl.type}}"></div>
  <div my-customer type="{{ctrl.type1}}"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

I hope it solves your problem